# Powershell - Getting a directory to output a file at a time

Tags: powershell

I'm super new at all of this so please excuse my lack of technical elegance and all around idiocy.

```
dir c:\Users\me\desktop\Test\*.txt | %{ $sourceFile = $_; get-content $_} | Out-File "$sourceFile.results"
```

How can I modify this command line so that instead of one file with the contents of all the text files I have a one to one ratio so that each output files represents the contents of each text file?

I realize that this object is ridiculous in terms of application but I'm conceptually trying to piece this together bit by bit so I can really understand.

P.S. What's with the %? Haha another ridiculous question, doesn't seem worth a separate post, what does it do?

Comment: Many of us lack technical elegance and are all-around idiots. But we love this stuff and we try hard to help each other out here.

Comment: The `%` is an alias for the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet which has another alias `foreach` (this is different than the `foreach` keyword).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dir | % { Out-File -FilePath "new_$($_.Name)" -InputObject (gc $_.FullName) }`

only one pipeline needed.  this command appends "new_" to the filename because I was using the same directory to write to.  You can remove this if it's not needed.